# error: "failed to emit precompiled header " when trying to build release version for ios in flutter project

Tags: ios, flutter, build

I am trying to build release version for ios in flutter project but getting error. i have successfully build for android and is ready to be release in play store but could not build for ios.

```
 <unknown>:0: error: failed to emit precompiled header '-----/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ffcffkmbdhvzbvdreompnmykxuan/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/Runner-Bridging-Header-swift_2UQTBPBSI3S8D-clang_7BTRW3ZHWAY7.pch' for
bridging header '----------/ios/Runner/Runner-Bridging-Header.h'
note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description
```

my flutter doctor -v gives

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.3, on macOS 11.2 20D64 darwin-x64, locale en-GB)
• Flutter version 2.5.3 at /Volumes/Macintosh HD - Data/development/flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision 18116933e7 (10 weeks ago), 2021-10-15 10:46:35 -0700
• Engine revision d3ea636dc5
• Dart version 2.14.4

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
• Android SDK at /Users/applefriend/Library/Android/sdk
• Platform android-31, build-tools 30.0.3
• Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6916264)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• Xcode 12.4, Build version 12D4e
• CocoaPods version 1.11.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.2)
• Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
   https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
   https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6916264)

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
• iPhone 12 Pro Max (mobile) • A54713A9-6BB0-42E6-85C6-7F337B206109 • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-14-4 (simulator)
• Chrome (web)               • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 96.0.4664.110

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Also having this issue. Did you find a solution? I have spent days trying to figure it out